# how to call xaml file on button onclick event in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, javascript, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have one html page which contains three button.in one button after clicking it should goto my contact list ,pick that contact and come back to that index.html page.i tried my code for contact chooser as sepratly and it runs correctly but i m not getting how to call the same contact chooser from button onclick funtion.please help if anybody knows thanks.this is my code below for contact chooser

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Resources;


namespace CordovaWP8_2_8_03
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
            phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
            phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();

        }
        void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The phone number for " + e.DisplayName + " is " + e.PhoneNumber);


               // PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
              //  phoneCallTask.DisplayName = e.DisplayName;
               // phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber;
              //  phoneCallTask.Show();
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: i have one html page ??

Comment: Is this a phone gap app or native app?

Comment: ya..its a phonegap app..in html page its contains the button which on click even should choose contact number from my phonebook and one textbox contains message to send to that number...

Comment: I'd better use the built-in code for choosing a number:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Comment: no i dont want to go that way..after very long effort i complted that contact chooser.just now i want to call it from my button onclick event..